# Are there any programs/applications/commands that will monitor and report GPU memory usage during a programs execution?

Tags: nvidia, software-recommendation

We're running algorithms on Ubuntu and we need to know how much memory the program uses. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I read a thread recently on one of the opencl forums that indicates it isn't really possible unless you build it in to your application for AMD/ATI cards due to some optimizations that make memory management outputs non-global

Comment: I've noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested in monitoring an Nvidia GPU you can use the `nvidia-smi` tool (installed with nvidia-current package). See these references:

- http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-system-management-interface
- http://www.matrix44.net/blog/?p=876

The latter in particular provides a nice script to output info.

For general memory and cpu usage, I'd go with `htop` (or `top`).  Or you can use `gnome-system-monitor` for a gui based tool.

Comment: Glad it helps... if it answers your question, please check the answer. We should both receive some reputation points then.